# RuntimeError: CUDA error: unspecified launch failure with python 3.7

Tags: pytorch, runtime-error, lstm

Training process started.To avoid cuda out of memory error, I set 1 to batch size.
But after a few epochs, sometimes even most of the time, I am getting  `RuntimeError: CUDA error: unspecified launch failure` error.It is very frustrating.
Every time I get the error, input size is changing so it is not happen same input.

train.py:

```py
for i, (inputs, target, _) in enumerate(train_loader):
    print(torch.cuda.is_available())
    input_var = [input.cuda() for input in inputs]
    target_var = target.cuda()
    output = model(input_var)
    loss = criterion(output, target_var)

losses.update(loss.item(), 1)

# compute accuracy
prec1, prec5 = accuracy(output.data.cpu(), target, topk=(1,5))
top1.update(prec1[0].item(), 1)
top5.update(prec5[0].item(), 1)

# zero the parameter gradients
optimizer.zero_grad()

# compute gradient
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

### .....

Output :

```
True
136
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "....\train.py", line 273, in <module>
    train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)

  File ".....\train.py", line 75, in train
    input_var = [input.cuda() for input in inputs]

  File "......\train.py", line 75, in <listcomp>
    input_var = [input.cuda() for input in inputs]

RuntimeError: CUDA error: unspecified launch failure
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix the error?
Thanks.

- Windows 10
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060
- Torch 1.6
- Cuda 10.1

---

Comment: Have you read this post? https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-get-rid-of-cudnn-unspecified-launch-failure-error-that-happens-after-a-few-epochs/61021

Comment: @YuchenZhong Does that from memory of Cuda or just I will try to set CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 to work as my code stopped at epoch 17 and the total is 20 epochs and took 10 days to run